# Retirar espaço no final de uma palavra

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-native

Criei um aplicativo em react native e o mesmo faz buscas online via POST. Ele funciona bem, a questão é que alguns aparelhos incluem um espaço no final das palavras, ex:

O usuário digita `natação`, mas o celular envia `natação_` com um espaço no final (botei underline só pra facilitar a visão).

Como faço pra retirar o espaço do final antes de fazer a consulta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chame o método `trim` da string antes de usá-la.

Experimente:

```
let foo = 'natação ';
console.log(foo.trim());
```

O método `trim` remove todos os espaços no fim da string, caso haja mais de um.

Comment: obrigado, só uma coisa: se tiver espaços entre as palavras ele exclui também? pois só preciso da exclusão no final

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo Não. `trim` é so no inicio e no fim da `String` toda. [Veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)